# OS161 expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before error

Tags: c, os161

I am working on the os161 project. I create a file which include the array.h provide in src/kern/include. When I compile, I had the error like this:
./../include/array.h:85: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'unsigned'
../../include/array.h:91: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'void'

the code is like:

```
#ifndef ARRAYINLINE
#define ARRAYINLINE INLINE
#endif

ARRAYINLINE unsigned    --------------line 85 error
array_num(const struct array *a)
{
    return a->num;
}

ARRAYINLINE void *     --------------line 91 error
array_get(const struct array *a, unsigned index)
{
    ARRAYASSERT(index < a->num);
    return a->v[index];
}
```

and this kind of error happened at every line has something like INLINE or ARRAYINLINE. This array.h file is provided and I made no change to it. Really cannot figure out why.

Comment: Can you add the const struct array please?
And a bit more code as well.
What is your command to compile?

Comment: Error says that the compiler is not able to understand what `INLINE` is. Maybe `#define ARRAYINLINE INLINE` is `define ARRAYINLINE inline` requesting the compiler to `inline` the functions? If not, is `INLINE` defined while compiling?

Comment: Try to get program text after preprocessor and show it. E.g. for gcc it's option "-E". The most probable variant is no definition of INLINE or strange one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on os161, too. `INLINE` is not defined, try using `#define ARRAYINLINE inline` instead.

[EDIT]

I checked my os161 revision. I found this line before the `#define ARRAYINLINE INLINE`

```
#define INLINE extern inline
```

So please check if your `array.h` also contains this line (115 in my case)

[/EDIT]

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on OS161 as well, this error could be generated if you have a random character outside of your function.
Example:

```
#include <...>
...
e //<-this random character that could have been mistyped.

sys_fork(...){
...
}
```